# Preventing Visual Studio 2017 from completing braces inside for loop declaration

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I've recently switched from using Visual Studio 2015 to the 2017 version and I'm having a bit of a problem. Let's say I start typing this line: `for(int i = 0; i < good.size)` (please note, that the last brace is put there by Visual Studio itself, not me). Next, I would type `(`, `)`, `;`. In Visual Studio 2015 this would become simply `for(int i = 0; i < good.size();)` and I could continue writing the `i++` part with no problems, but in Visual Studio 2017 this translates to `for (int i = 0; i < good.size());`, which is definitely not what I want, as I then have to go back and fix the code, which reduces my overall typing speed. I'm guessing there should be a setting of some sort to fix this? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you're using C#:

In Visual Studio, go to:

Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Uncheck "Automatic brace completion"

Or for all languages:

Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages > Uncheck "Automatic brace completion"

[image]

Comment: That would be good, but this disable all the brace completion. I like that feature, I just don't like how it completes braces when you're inside other braces. As Visual Studio 2015 didn't have this, I though there would be some easy way to fix it 2017 as well. Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: Glad to help. Have a great day.

Comment: For more advanced settings like you wanted, I suggest you work with tools like ReSharper.